# How to make a file present in two variants but not in the third one?

Tags: android, gradle

if a `java file` exists in the `main directory` presents in all variants. and if we want that file presents in `variant 1` but not in `variant 2`, we move that file from `main directory` to `variant1` specific directory.
now if we want that file presents in two variants but not third one, what should we do?

i don't want to copy file for both two variants of course, because in this case, the changes must be applied twice.

Comment: What is that java file? a class?

Comment: @W0rmH0le yes it's a class

Comment: You can achieve that using different `flavorDimensions`: a flavor dimension for that file, and then add 2 flavors in that dimension - first one having file, second - not having it. Then add the flavor having the file into required build types